# Relation of swappines and zram

Tags: ram, zram

I have been interested in `zram` so I tried to test it. But as I continue to read the guide on what and how to install it, I have realized that it creates a file `/dev/zram0` and mounts it as a swap, I use `mount` to know it. I have set the swappiness of the OS on a value of 10. Will this affect the chances that `zram` will be used? If yes, do I have to set it on a higher value?

Answer (score 0):

1. `mount` doesn't show swap devices, `swapon -s` does.
2. How did you "install" it? On Ubuntu [zram-config](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=zram-config) does everything.
3. How do you expect to test it?
4. It works if your system doesn't immediately die.
5. [vm.swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) sets the "chances" of swap devices being used. `swapon -s` again tells you what is being used.

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition   1952764 0   -1
/dev/zram0                              partition   705000  21660   5
/dev/zram1                              partition   705000  21624   5
```